# The location service is abnormal after flutter background service is used

Tags: flutter

Flutter version 3.7.12 and 3.10.6.
dependencies:
flutter_bmflocation: ^3.4.1
flutter_background_service: ^3.0.2 and 5.0.0

After use the flutter_background_service,the flutter_bmflocation location function in my app became unusable on the interface, but it can still be used in flutter_background_service.

I tried to have the service open in the background and closed in the foreground
service.startService();
service.invoke("onDataReceived", {'action' : 'stopService'});
A detailed error has occurred after
error log:

```
D/baidu_location_client(21180): baidu location connected ...
W/FlutterJNI(21180): Tried to send a platform message to Flutter, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send. Channel: flutter_bmflocation. Response ID: 3
```

I tried other background service plugins like android_alarm_manager_plus with the same results